# Formatting Dates Across Several Tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm currently performing a union across 4 different tables in which the dates are currently a combination of date and datetime fields.

If I use "Format" to change the dates, it'll turn the date column into an nvarchar data type which I do not want.

How can I then, format each of the dates in each of the tables for uniformity while maintaining the data type as date in the outputted view?

Below is the SQL script I used previously, which turned my dates into an nvarchar data type

```
FORMAT(Date,'MM/dd/yy') 'Date'
```

The final data type would be date

Comment: you have to convert each field to the datatype you finally want, which interestingly enough you have not mentioned.

Comment: I have indicated that the final data type would be 'date' which two of the four tables are already using as a the data type. It's converting the other two datetime data types that's at the center of the question.

Comment: convert(date,yourfields)

Comment: can you give information about the DATE field present in all other tables et can you give your UNION and not simply a simple line with FORMAT ?

Comment: George Menoutis's comment did the trick

Comment: Yes, perhaps. But the Question/Answer is not only for you but for all the community. It is then important that a question is well written/documented and that the answer is put in Answer and not in Comment.

Comment: I have posted the answer to the question, which should satisfy this question and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct query for my question is convert(date,yourfields) per George Menoutis